# How to pass array of stdlib list by reference

Tags: c++, std

I am a beginner in C++ stdlib. I learnt stdlib tutorials and I am implementing "number of connected components in Graph" using adjacency list created with stdlib lists. I wanted to know how to pass this array of list by reference to `dfs` function? Also, one of my frnd said that by default it will be passed by reference. Is it true? Please clarify. which of these is right?

for example:

1. My array of list: `list<int> L[v];`
2. My function call: `dfs(L[v],k);`
3. My function definition: `void dfs(list<int> List, int index);`
4. My function prototype: `void dfs(list<int> L, int);`

(or)

1. My array of list: `list<int> L[v];`
2. My function call: `dfs(L,k);`
3. My function definition: `void dfs(list<int> *L, int index);`
4. My function prototype: `void dfs(list<int> *, int);`

Comment: The default in C++ is pass by value.

Comment: @karlphillip: Unless the argument is an array (or a function), in which case it's converted to a pointer and the effect is more like passing by reference.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Honestly not sure what's best here: to pretend we have pass-by-reference semantics, or to explain that it's pass-by-value semantics on a pointer. I suspect the latter, even though it jumps into some complex territory; I think the damage potentially done by the former outweights that risk though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to know how to pass this array of list by reference to dfs function? Also, one of my frnd said that by default it will be passed by reference.

Not quite.

First of all, let's forget about the `std::list`; it's just confusing matters.

Pretend you're passing an array of `int` instead:

```
void foo(int[] x);

int main() {
   int x[5];
   foo(x);
}
```

There are no references here, and C++ arguments are *copied* by default, but because arrays cannot be copied and because the name of an array decays to the name of a pointer to the first element in the array, you're passing a [copy of a] *pointer* not the array itself.

In fact, `void foo(int[] x)` is misleading syntactic sugar for the equivalent, and clearer `void foo(int* x)`.

In particular note that — in *both* cases — the function `foo` does not know the dimension of the original array.

This is kind of old-fashioned, though, and you *can* pass an actual reference to an array:

```
void foo(int (&x)[5]);

int main() {
   int x[5];
   foo(x);
}
```

Now we can apply this same logic to arrays of `std::list`:

```
void foo(std::list<int>*); // pointer to one or more lists, OR
void foo(std::list<int> (&)[5]); // reference to an array of five lists
```

Anyway, mixing standard containers and arrays seems odd; prefer a `std::vector` over an array, or a wrapper around statically-allocated arrays (like `std::array` or, previously, `boost::array`) if you really need the automatic storage duration for some reason.

---

Also, your call syntax is wrong.

> My function call: dfs(L[v],k);
>   My function definition: void dfs(list List, int index);

This passes a single list from the array of lists, and does so by value/copying.

Comment: Thanks, for the advice. I will look into vectors too.

Comment: btw, you said that my function call and definition are wrong. I have mentioned a second version <in my original post> after (or) trying to pass by reference. Looking at  wat you say, that seems to be right. Is it?

Comment: I mean to say:
void dfs(list<int> *L, int index): definition
dfs(L,k);
--these seems to be right when I look at your explanation

Comment: @SaranyaDeviGanesan: Yes, the second version is ok, for passing a pointer-to-list(s).

Answer (score 1):

To pass by reference, use `&`:

```
void dfs(const vector< list<int> >& L, int index);
// ...
vector< list<int> > L(v);
dfs(L, k);
```

Objects of non-builtin types are usually passed by reference to const to avoid copies. Passing by value is the default for all types, you have to specify reference semantics explicitly. Note that I've used a `vector` instead of a C array, which is usually preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have an actual array of lists:

```
std::list<int> matrix[N];
```

To pass the whole array to a function you can do one of two things. The C way would be passing a pointer to the first element together with the size of the array:

```
return_type
dfs( std::list<int> const * array, std::size_t size, int key ); // signature

dfs( matrix, N, k );                                        // caller
```

The C++ way... well, there are different C++ ways. I would recommend not using an array, but rather a vector (and since we are at it, change the list into a vector too):

```
return_type
dfs( std::vector< std::vector<int> > const & adj, int key ); // signature

std::vector< std::vector<int> > adj_list;
dfs( adj_list, k );
```

If you really want to keep using arrays and lists and passing by reference, then the syntax would be:

```
const int N = 10;

return_type
dfs( std::list<int> (&adj)[N], int k );

std::list<int> adj_list[N];
dfs( adj_list, k );
```

Note that in this case the size of the array `N` is fixed at compile time (can be made a bit more generic by using a template, but it will still be resolved at compile time).

I would recommend that you redesign your data structure to be a vector of vectors, though.

Answer (score -1):

If your array of lists is declared like this:

```
list<int> L[v];
```

Then the correct way to pass by reference is:

```
void dfs(list<int> & L, int index);
```

Your function call will then look like this:

```
dfs(L[v], k);
```

Answer (score -1):

FYI, the default in C++ is pass-by-copy/value.

Let's adjust your code to use the traditional pass-by-reference method:

1. Array of list: `list<int> L[v];`
2. Function call: `dfs(L,k);`
3. Function definition: `void dfs(list<int>& L, int index);`
4. Function prototype:  `void dfs(list<int>& , int);`

Of course, the `&` can be place either near the parameter type ot the parameter name.

This method essentially passes a pointer. Not the same kind of pointer you would get when doing `list<int>* L`. That is why it is called *by reference*.

And inside `dfs(list<int>& L, int index)`, you will use/access `L` as if it were a regular variable.

I think [this blog](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1232/c-pointers-pass-by-value-pass-by-reference/) post explains it well.

Comment: That was copied/pasted from the original question, give me a break. I think I'll change my picture to a female too. It seems to give more upvotes. =D

Comment: But you copy/pasted the part of the question that was a wrong implementation of the stated requirements :)